# count every element of a data Frame in R

Tags: r

I'm looking for a way to count each element of my data frame, but that data frame is very big, with 29 columns and some NA's.

I already tried with `table(myData)`  but I'm still getting the error

`Error in table(myData) : attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements`

How do I count each element in the data frame? I need something like

`item frequency
3      3
45     4
24     1
6      5`

Comment: A little more info on what your data looks like would be helpful. You might find this post helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/3691003

Comment: Is there a reason you have a data frame and not a matrix? Do rows or column have any meaning? Is everything integers?

Comment: I'd try `table(unlist(myData))`.

Answer (score 0):

Given we know so little about your data, I would try doing whatever you are doing with the first few rows. E.g.

```
testData <- head(myData, 10)
```

You'll probably then see more clearly how you might have abused the 'table' function.